# Is there a shortcut key for accessing the menu bar?

Tags: unity, 11.04, keyboard, menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard shortcuts in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/keyboard-shortcuts-in-unity)

Is there a shortcut key for accessing the menu bar of an application? (Not Ubuntu's menu.) I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd>, but no luck. I don't want to access a specific menu, just the menu bar so I could use the arrows to go between the menus.

I'm using 11.04 Alpha-2.

Comment: I started a page documenting them all now that we have an idea how they're shaping up.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean Ubuntu menu? It is `Alt` + `F1`.

For window menu, use `Alt` + `Space`. For e.g. File menu, just hold down `Alt` and see what letter is underlined. Example: `Alt` + `F`

Read more on: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are useing 11.04 - Unity. I did not yet tried it.

Comment: These don't work, you might as well delete this answer. I meant the application's menu bar, not Ubuntu's.