# Shortcut to access menu bar

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, menu, menu-bar

I turned off the menu bar on Okular and cannot get it to show up again such that I can set it to be permanently displayed. Is there a keyboard shortcut I can use to do this?

(Similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26150/is-there-a-shortcut-key-for-accessing-the-menu-bar) which has no working answers and was closed as a duplicate even though the ["duplicate"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts) doesn't contain a working answer either {although it is very comprehensive otherwise})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, which worked perfectly, so asked a new question so I could provide the answer.

Comment: Would never have guessed Ctrl+M (but maybe that's what comes from running a KDE app in Ubuntu).  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ctrl+M seems to do nothing in Ubuntu Unity 22.04 LTS when in `xed` or on the desktop, in Firefox it just (un-)mutes the current tab.