# How can I reset Okular to show the title bar and menu again?

Tags: okular

For a short time the window of Okular always opens in a kind of full screen mode in my Xubuntu 20.04. The title bar and the menu are inaccessible in this mode.

I can't get out of this mode with **ESC**. I can only quit the program with **Alt-F4**.

Comment: Does a right-click offers you the option to leave full-screen-mode? Did you try `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for **Menubar** of the Okular app. By default, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> is set to show and hide the Menubar.

So once you show the menubar you can show or hide different panels on the settings menu.

Comment: There are two different settings, one is the fullscreen mode which is toggled by Ctl-Shift-f, the other one is the menu bar, which is controlled by Ctl-m. Both of them work independently, i.e. there is a fullscreen mode with or without menu bar and there is a non-fullscreen mode with or without menu bar. The answer of https://askubuntu.com/questions/969813/shortcut-to-access-menu-bar is right and my question actually is a duplicate of it. But the answers also led to leaving the full screen mode, which is also helpful in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mook765!

**Ctrl+Shift+F** did it!

It seems to be a toggle-key to switch between full screen mode and normal mode in Okular, but not in other applications I have tried.